# Object [object Object] has no method 'calendricalDate'

Tags: jquery

I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'calendricalDate'
```

I am trying to use this [plugin](https://github.com/tobico/jquery-calendrical). The weird thing is that it has been working and just all the sudden it stopped.
Here's the jQuery code:

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.calendrical.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#salida, #llegada').calendricalDate();
        $('#salida_time, #llegada_time').calendricalTime();
    });
</script>
```

And the js file is exactly the same from the website, I just copied and pasted.  It might be something really dumb that I may have overlooked, so any help is more than appreciated.
Here's more detailed error:

```
14Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'calendricalDate'
(anonymous function)              enviotracking.php:14
o.extend.ready.o.readyList        jquery-1.3.2.min.js:19
o.extend.each                     jquery-1.3.2.min.js:12
o.extend.ready                    jquery-1.3.2.min.js:19
o.each.o.fn.(anonymous function)
```

line 14 on the php file is DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Ok this is weird I have another page which has the same code and it works but I did a breakdown of when was the error happening so I took everything out and started added my code 1 by 1 and I noticed when I add this:

```
<script src="../js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("ul.subnav").parent().append("<span></span>"); //Only shows drop down trigger when js is enabled (Adds empty span tag after ul.subnav*)

        $("ul.topnav li span").click(function() { //When trigger is clicked...

            //Following events are applied to the subnav itself (moving subnav up and down)
            $(this).parent().find("ul.subnav").slideDown('fast').show(); //Drop down the subnav on click

            $(this).parent().hover(function() {
            }, function(){
                $(this).parent().find("ul.subnav").slideUp('slow'); //When the mouse hovers out of the subnav, move it back up
            });

            //Following events are applied to the trigger (Hover events for the trigger)
            }).hover(function() {
                $(this).addClass("subhover"); //On hover over, add class "subhover"
            }, function(){  //On Hover Out
                $(this).removeClass("subhover"); //On hover out, remove class "subhover"
        });

    });
</script>
```

Is when my code breaks.  But that doesn't happen anywhere else :(

Comment: check the firebug console for any javascript errors

Comment: are you sure about the jquery version because on the plugin site in `example.html` there is `version 1.4.2` of jquery is  used

Comment: I tried that aswell the 1.4.2 and same error. @3nigma in chrome thats the exact error message I'm assuming firebug would be the same?

Comment: Are your sure the relative path "../js/jquery.calendrical.js" is correct ?

Comment: @DidierG. yes I haven't changed the path to none of the files.  I thought that would of been it, but no everything is linked correctly.  I also checked with dreamweaver you know when you link something it gives you a tab so you can see it without opening the file itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To close this off I figured out it wasn't the path it was another jquery script that was causing a conflict. And I didn't even need it, after removing the extra script everything worked.  Thanks for everyone's effort!

Answer (score 0):

Applying separately works:

Try this:

```
$('#salida').calendricalDate();
$('#llegada').calendricalDate();
```

Comment: Forget this, it's still early morning, it works your way too: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/d6EsR/)